# C++: What is semantics of std::function constness?

Tags: c++11

Reference says that `std::function::operator()` is `const`. What this constness applies to? If `std::function` is a wrapper around callable object, does constness applies to this object (meaning its `operator()` should be `const` too?).

Overall, what does it mean for `std::function` to be const for different kinds of targets (lambda, function pointer, object, member function, etc)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a bug. Nothing is actually `const` as the target object is called from a non-`const` reference, per the specification.

A future revision of the standard library will remove `const` from the call operator. Users will be able to specifically request a properly `const` call using specializations such as `std::function<return_type(arg_type) const>`.

See standard proposal [P0045](https://wg21.link/P0045). (Disclosure: I'm the author.)

Comment: thanks for clarifiing about `operator()`. Could you please answer to the second part of the question? When I, for example, pass `std::function` by const reference, what this constness mean?

Comment: @DmitryJ Currently, all the `const` semantics are meaningless because the call operator throws it away (as if by `const_cast`). Once the library bug ticket is fixed, for example by my proposal, then an ordinary `std::function<void()>` will not even be callable from a `const` reference.

Comment: @Potatoswatter I had the exact same question yesterday when I had to deal with a const std::function and started wondering if the call operator being const means, the bound object/member-func must also be const. The answer was it didn't have to but I reasoned it was because the const only applies to the state of std::function but if the bound object is stored as a member variable then I guess the member func it calls must also be const?

Comment: @ForeverLearning Yes, that conundrum was one of the first motivations listed in my proposal. The bound object may indeed be stored as a member variable, for the small-object optimization, and the implementation needs a `const_cast` to treat it as non-const. This may be unsafe and it's hard to guarantee that an implementation of `std::function` is working properly at all.